# How to fire Azure AD login MFA second step in Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure-active-directory, blazor

In my scenario a Azure AD user already login into my blazor application.
But when that user try to go a "**More Protected**" URL I want to do MFA second step.
As like as OneDrive Personal vault doing.

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFOl9.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFOl9.png)]

Last few days I do lot's search event ask Chat GPT but does not find any solution.

My question is how can I achieve this.

Thanks for your help.